prevent watched elements from calling updates on each other
How can I prevent watched elements from calling updates on each other in Vuejs?
const width = ref(0);
const height = ref(0);

watch(width, async (newItem, oldItem) => {
    console.log(`width: ${oldItem}->${newItem}`);
    height.value = newItem / 2;
});

watch(height, async (newItem, oldItem) => {
    console.log(`height: ${oldItem}->${newItem}`);
    width.value = newItem * 2;
});


as a result, I can see output like this in the console
width: 1->2
height: 0.5->1
width: 2->2

Full vuejs code:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { watch } from 'vue'

const width = ref(0);
const height = ref(0);

watch(width, async (newItem, oldItem) => {
    console.log(`width: ${oldItem}->${newItem}`);
    height.value = newItem / 2;
});

watch(height, async (newItem, oldItem) => {
    console.log(`height: ${oldItem}->${newItem}`);
    width.value = newItem * 2;
});
</script>

<template>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="details">
            <h3>
                Width {{ width }}
            </h3>
            <input v-model="width" placeholder="0" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="details">
            <h3>
                Height {{ height }}
            </h3>
            <input v-model="height" placeholder="0" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>



i guess the full code is needed that triggers the watches

the best is to recreate the problem on the playground https://play.vuejs.org/

the template is very simple, with just 2 input fields. I added it to the question.

If you output the values with JSON.stringify you'll notice that the type is changed from string to number due calculations:
Playground
width: 0->"2"
height: 0->1
width: "2"->2

Just use v-model.number="width" to operate on numbers only: Playground
To avoid entering non-numeric values I would suggest to use keydown event:
const preventAlpha = e => {
    if(/[^\d.]/.test(e.key) && e.key.length === 1){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else 
    if(e.key === '.' && e.target.value.includes('.')){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else 
    if(e.target.value === '' && e.key === '.'){
        e.target.value = '0';
    }
}
const vNumber = {
    mounted: el => el.addEventListener('keydown', preventAlpha),
    unmounted: el => el.removeEventListener('keydown', preventAlpha)
}

Playground
UPDATE
Answer the comment: there's usually no need to prevent the second watch since it's settled after and no further watches are invoked. Otherwise I don't know a way to change a ref silently, but you could make manual checks:
let changing = false;

watch(width, async (newItem, oldItem) => {
    if(changing) return;
    console.log(`width: ${JSON.stringify(oldItem)}->${JSON.stringify(newItem)}`);
    changing = true;
    height.value = newItem / 2;
    await 1;
    changing = false;
});

watch(height, async (newItem, oldItem) => {
    if(changing) return;
    console.log(`height: ${JSON.stringify(oldItem)}->${JSON.stringify(newItem)}`);
    changing = true;
    width.value = newItem * 2;
    await 1;
    changing = false;
});

Playground

Thanks! It reduces the calls to 2 then
width: 0->4
height: 0->2

Is there any way to avoid the second watch call at all?

@kikulikov updated the answeer

I see. Thanks a lot! How does "v-number" translate to "vNumber"? Where can I read about it?

@kikulikov look for directives in the docs
